# How to estimate OpenGL ES shader/Metal performance in GFlops

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, metal, flops

How to estimate OpenGL ES shader/Metal performance in GFlops?

iPhone X GPU is believed to have 350 GFlops in theory. (Ref from http://blog.filippkeks.com/2017/09/21/horrors-of-mobile-graphics.html)

I want to how many GFlops my OpenGL ES shader/ Metal code can achieve.

Is there a way to check the GFlops performance for iOS/Xcode?

Comment: "*I want to how many GFlops my OpenGL ES shader/ Metal code can achieve.*" Does it matter? Flops is not a useful metric of how fast a shader is. It's far more useful to just measure how fast the shader is. And it's the actual performance of the shader that will matter in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run the code on different devices, and record the time you code needed. Then calculate the GFlops by the device's GFlops it claimed in its specification.

For example, run on a 200GFlops device need 10ms, you can calculate your code need 2GFlops. Then you know on another 300GFlops device, your code may need 6.6ms. It will be not very exactly, but just for estimate you code runtime on different devices.